# border of plot only partly displayed in gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot

I am plotting a matlab plot into an axes inside a matlab gui.

This works in principle fine, but the border of the axis is only visible by chance.
I however want to ensure that the plot is displayed correct.

[image]

I assume that this has to do with rounding in the renderer. However since this is inside the gui I wonder if I can change the renderer only for this plot ?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What border do you mean? What is correct and what would be incorrect?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html explains how you can change the renderer for your figure, however I don't know whether it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error is triggered because of another plot that uses transparency which requires the `opengl` renderer. The opengl however has a principle rounding problem which leads to missing lines as visible in my plot shown in the question.

If I switch the render for this plot to `painters` everything works as expected.

For the other plot I then have to switch back to `opengl`, but since both are not displayed at the same time this is not a problem.